# How to mark pin points on a map in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, dictionary, geolocation

I have a list of geo-location points (`the tuples of longitude and latitude`) and they are all `text`.

Now, I want to use those text values to draw the `pin points` on a same map by `Java` on PC and output is a static image with all `pin points` (want to look at the tendency of distribution)

Is there a good way/source to get the corresponding map and draw the pin points out in Java? (I did not find a map source for Java. I have tried using Google map API, but it might not support Java well and if the number of locations is too large, it might not work....)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an open source about this called OpenStreetMap which is so good

http://www.openstreetmap.org/